# How to define derivative of function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

Could you help me, please? I'd like to evaluate the following expression:

`f' := 1/g[x]`

`L[x_]:=L[x]=D[f[x]g[x], x]`

Thus, I'm expecting to see that

`L[x]=1 + f[x]g'[x]`.

How can I define f' to see this result? Can I do it in such a way that will allow me to keep using "D[]"?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does `f' =.; ClearAll[f]; f'[x_] := 1/g[x];` work for you? (Or `f /: f' := 1/g[#] &`?) Beware that your definition and my first one define a value for `Derivative`, not `f`.  It has to be cleared with `Unset`, that is `f' =.` or `f'[x_] =.`, or `Clear[Derivative]`, which will clear all user-defined `Derivative` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is almost correct. You just need to change`f' := 1/g[x]` to `f'[x_] := 1/g[x]`. Using `L[x]`, you will obtain the desired result

Comment: Indeed! Thank you!